# How to set HTTPS as default on nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, https

I have working SSL enabled domain , server and it's up and running `HTTP` as default. explicitly when I request `https://domain.tld` it works fine but How to make it as default instead of `HTTP`

right now I have the following directives of my nginx vhost

```
server {

    listen 80 ;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    ssl on ;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/XX.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/XX.key;

    server_name x.me www.x.me;
    root /usr/share/nginx/www/x/site;
    index index.html index.php;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

redirect http requests to https. This can be done with scripting, but also with nginx using 'return'.

Tutorial: https://christiaanconover.com/blog/how-to-redirect-http-to-https-in-nginx

Answer (score 3):

Add a separate server, that will redirect to https:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name x.me www.x.me;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

and remove `listen 80` from your existing code block

Comment: where to put it ? will it placed to my existing above block ?

Comment: Yes, add the 'return' directive to your server block.

Comment: Chrome returns me ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS , my current server block http://pastebin.com/HW1A3XVf